# What is SELECT 1=1 FROM TABLE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I found a query in MySql stored procedure where

```
 SELECT 1=1 FROM ITEM_TABLE WHERE product_code = productCode;
```

What does this `1=1` means? is it means a `boolean` `true`?
The outputs was few rows of `1`. 
What does the output means? Do we really need to perform this type of check?

Comment: Why not try to run the query?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes they use this phrase to break the query in Sql Injection
In essence, it means a condition is always true

Sometimes it is used to create multiple searches
For Example :

```
 string x ;
 x="select * from tbl_test where 1=1";
 if(txtId.text != ""){

  x += " And id=" + txtId.text + "";

 }
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The answer of 1=1 is always yes, a true scenario or condition.

It will output you a column of true values. Did you try it out before asking?

Comment: Yeah. I had tried. It returns some rows of 1's.
Okay. I got it. It will return '1' if one row met the WHERE condition.

Comment: IF 1=1 is in the WHERE condition it will not add a column of true values to the output, it literally means: select the record when 1 = 1, in short show all records. Expressions in the where clause are not part of the output columns, they just control which records should be included.